# Why it seems two ip addresses are assigned to the same guest in Virtual Box?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, docker, sandbox

I have a VirtualBox guest installed on my Windows 7 host, which is a hortonwork sandbox.

The sandbox is up and running as below:

[image]

From the output, it indicates using localhost:4200 to access it via SSH.

for localhost, in my hosts file it is defined as below:

```
192.168.2.29 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.2.29 sandbox.hortonworks.com sandbox
```

So I use `192.168.2.29:4200` to access the host via SSH (in browser), however, it connects but showing from `172.18.0.2`, if I run **ifconfig**, it also shows `172.18.0.2` as the ip address. here is the screenshot:

[image]

here is the /tmp folder:
[image]

BUT, if I ssh into the `192.168.2.29` (Putty), I see different content in the /tmp folder:
[image]

**NOTE: Browser SSH shows a completely different content than Putty SSH**

If I attempt to Putty SSH to `172.18.0.2`, it will fail as below:

[image]

What is the real ip address? How can I connect to the guest via WinScp to the guest showing in **Browser SSH**?

VirtualBox guest's networking is set as Bridged, see below:
[image]

Windows host networking is below:

[image]

Thank you very much.

UPDATE 20190909: If I attempted to SSH into 192.168.2.29:2222 as per suggested in @Anaksunaman's answer, I got rejected as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A couple points:

- It appears as if the `172.x.x.x` address is possibly a private network created by the sandbox itself. So it would make sense you couldn't log in to it.
- Regarding the difference in `tmp` folders, there are two different users (`root@sandbox-host` and `root@sandbox-hdf`), so that would likely explain the difference.

> What is the real ip address?

Based on your post, `192.168.2.29` seems to be the "real" IP (for VirtualBox).

> How can I connect to the guest via WinSCP to the guest showing in the browser SSH session?

Based on some Googling, you may want to try logging into the sandbox via SSH on port 2222 (so `192.168.2.29:2222` or `localhost:2222`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I tried in putty the ip:2222, it leads me to `root@sandbox-host`, I also tried WinScp and browser on this port 2222, they don't even let me in. Maybe there should be another bridge for connecting 172.x.x.x with 192.x.x.x?

Comment: I believe the port 2222 suggestion comes from an old sandbox. I am using the latest HDF 3.1.1 sandbox for VirtualBox. I've updated my OP with error screenshot. Thank you.